# Change "drawingMode" in drawingManager of Google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Look at this code:
This is a Google tool that creates a panel on the map and helps us to draw shapes. By the `drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE` we can indicate that which tool was selected at the first load but I want to change it in the program. For example I want to change CIRCLE to POLYGON by clicking a button. How can I do something like this?

```
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
        ]
    }
    });
```

Comment: drawingManager.set('drawingMode');

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your case, if you would like to change the drawingMode to CIRCLE you would have to use the following JavaScript:

```
drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE);
```

This overwrite the currently used drawingMode by the one set by the above method. This follows the official Google Maps documentation.

Accepted values

```
google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER
google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE
```

Taken from [source](https://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/3.8/com/google/maps/gwt/client/drawing/DrawingManager.html#setDrawingMode(com.google.maps.gwt.client.drawing.OverlayType)):

> public final void **setDrawingMode**(OverlayType drawingMode)
>
> Changes the DrawingManager 's drawing mode, which defines the type of
> overlay to be added on the map. Accepted values are MARKER , POLYGON ,
> POLYLINE , RECTANGLE , CIRCLE , or null . A drawing mode of null means
> that the user can interact with the map as normal, and clicks do not
> draw anything.

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me. But I don't know if it is a standard way or no?

```
drawingManager.set('drawingMode');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my post. This will help you out. I have done it with the following. Having three methods which is used to draw three different shapes to be drawn. (initiatePolygon() , initiateRectangle() , initiateCircle() )

[How to enable and disable the drawingControlOptions in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852361/how-to-enable-and-disable-the-drawingcontroloptions-in-google-maps?answertab=active#tab-top)