# Google map - Highlight boundaries

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to highlight the boundaries like this on google map ? 
I have the coordinates and I want to get this result when the map loads.

[image]

Comment: Yes. It's called a [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Polyline).

Comment: @ArunRaj He didn't change the topic or the question itself. He improved it with more information, which is a good thing. Your comment is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) and working example [Google Map Draw Polyline](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools).

Comment: I think Polyline is not a good option to highlight closed boundaries which is displayed like in the question.

Comment: @ArunRaj Why would it not be? Thanks to let us know!

Comment: @MrUpsidown : Really simple, You can see the region which was drawn has been closed. Closed POlYGONAL CHAIN (Ofcourse polyline) is referred to as Polygon. And also in the question itself, he mentioned boundaries (It is a closed object) not a line. So implementing with polyline is not the best idea for the closed object / region. I have delivered as per my knowledge. Still if you find any query, Feel free.

Comment: Ok, I give you this one. Then you can go for a [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Polygon) with a `fillOpacity` set at zero.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can highlight your boundaries.

It can be done in many ways.

1. By rendering KML [Layer](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut)
2. By using google drawingAPI.

I would recommend to go with Option1.

**For your reference :**

[Demo 1 - Option 1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml) - Simple example to render kml file. LineStrings are used here. But you need polygon as per your example says.

[Demo 2 - Option 1](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_us_states_simple.html) - State of USA has been displayed with their boundaries. Here polygon has been used to display.

[Demo 3 - Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20883065/2959196) - Displays constant triangle shape.